# How to add values from multiple tuples?

Tags: python, tuples, multiplication

So I am trying to create a program which will return stock profit and the values are stored in a tuple. The values are stored in the manner of (stock symbol, #of shares, price bought, price sold). For example:

```
('CAT', 25, 43.50, 67.75), ("MSFT', 100, 87.65, 82.50).
```

To calculate profit I am using the formula:

```
shares * (price sold - price bought)
```

How do I take the values from these tuples to calculate total profit from the two stocks? I have written some code but not sure how to proceed.

```
def stocks_value(portfolio):    
    total = 0
    for value in portfolio:
        total = value[1] * (value[3] - value[2])
        return total
```

Comment: You are currently overwriting the total value on each loop iteration. Instead, do `total += values....`.

Answer (score 3):

Will this do what you need?:

```
def stocks_value(portfolio):    
    total = 0
    for value in portfolio:
        total += value[1] * (value[3] - value[2])
    return total
```

You could also try:

```
total = sum(value[1] * (value[3] - value[2]) for value in portfolio)
```

Comment: Props for the minimized uber - pythonic summation.

Answer (score 0):

Values of tuples are treated indexed like lists.  Assuming `portfolio` is a list of tuples it looks like your code is mostly correct, just change `total = value[1] ...`  to `total += value[1] ...` if you're trying to find the grand sum of profit totals

Comment: Thank you! That seems to be what I missed